# How to find and read metadata using jQuery (schema.org microformat)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a Google Maps application and I'd like to read out the metadata, as specified by [schema.org](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), from my HTML to plot my map markers.

For example:

```
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
...some html... 
  <div class="geo" itemprop="geo" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
    <meta itemprop="latitude" content="43.681505" />
    <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-79.294455" />
  </div>
</li>
```

Is there an easy way to query out the latitude and longitude values without having loop through everything?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
jQuery(function($){
  var latitude = $('.geo meta[itemprop="latitude"]').attr("content");
  var longitude = $('.geo meta[itemprop="longitude"]').attr("content");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get at the data like so:

`$('meta[itemprop="latitude"]').attr('content')`