# Accessing Resx in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, innerhtml, resx

Okay I trying to make site handle different languages so I am using a resx file.

I can display simply Welcome on aspx page like this:

```
<asp:Label runat='server' ID="foo" meta:resourcekey='WelcomeText'/>
```

Now I want to be able to use javascript to do innerHTML:

```
"<div>
    <asp:Label runat='server' ID="foo" meta:resourcekey='WelcomeText'/>
</div>"
```

But it does not work like that. I have tried to also do getElementById which keeps returning null.

Any Ideas?

Comment: why don't you call directly `<%=YourResourceName.WelcomeText%>`

Comment: Can you show a little more code? But marathonman seems to have the right solution.

Comment: @Remy basically in javascript I am going to need to pass a string to another class to display some text. And right now I can pass the string with HTML elements in it and it will work correctly. For example I can add a link within the string using <a href>. Now when sending that string I want to be able to add the text from the resx file called WelcomeText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read like

```
var author = $('meta[name=author]').attr("content");
```

[Is it possible to use jQuery to read meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags)

[How to find and read metadata using jQuery (schema.org microformat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969414/how-to-find-and-read-metadata-using-jquery-schema-org-microformat)

Comment: I think this is the right approach. But I am a little confused what exactly to put in the statement (here is what I have tried)

    var welcome = $('meta[name=WelcomeText]').attr("content")
    var welcome = $('meta[name=resourcekey]').attr("WelcomeText")